# about the terms of "Component"

Tags: android, terminology

I'm a newbie of Android world. I'm so confused about some terms.
Especially, why do we call Activity, Service, Broadcast receiver and Content Provider as "Component"? Of course, I know the original meaning of Component. However, I think there are special reasons that Android developers use this terminology. Please somebody tell me exactly meaning or definition about Component.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, as far as I know there is no special Android-specific meaning of "Component". Activities, Services, Broadcast Receivers and Content Providers are just core building blocks of a standard Android application so they are called application components. The docs use the term "component" in other places to refer to other things too, see [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) for an example.

Comment: hey man,..Now, my instructor told us that Component is different from application because that has life cycles. Namely, if some app has life cycles, it can be said "component". Is this right?

Comment: @Holy The life cycle you are talking about is clearly stated in the [official dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#Components)